# Python re.findall assist in writing code

Tags: python, python-2.7

The assignment is to read through the file extracting all of the numbers from the text file, have them in a list, and get a sum of the numbers. Here is the code I have written, which doesn’t work. I know it has to do with the line after `re.findall`

```
import re

handle=open('regex_sum_42.txt')

mylist=[]

for lines in handle:

    numbers=re.findall('([0-9]+)',lines)

    if len(numbers)>0:

        #print numbers

sum=0

for numbers in numlist:

    print sum(numlist)
```

Comment: Can you show us what `regex_sum_42.txt` looks like?  You say the code you've written doesn't work, but how does it fail?  If there's an error, what's the error?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
import re
handle=open('regex_sum_42.txt')
mylist=[]
for lines in handle:
   numbers=re.findall(r'[0-9]+',lines)
   mylist=mylist+numbers
def sum(list):
   sum=0
   for i in list:
       sum=sum+int(i)
   return sum
print sum(mylist)
```

I created a test file with name regex_sum_42.txt and I assume that your file looks like this:

a10e45
b20e55
.......

If this does not work, please let me know how your regex_sum_42.txt looks like. Thanks!